# The test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I want to debug my webmethod to see if the returning list contains the object that had been passed as a parameter.

**My webmethod is as follows:**

```
[WebMethod]
       public List<Vehicle> GetCustomerList(Vehicle obj)
            {
                //List<Vehicle> newL = new List<Vehicle> { obj };

                return new List<Vehicle> { obj };

            }
```

It says "The test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters". SO i want to know what changes i need to make in order to be able to check what is being passed by the method.

**> EDITED CODE FOR A FOLLOW UP QUESTION**

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

   [WebMethod]
             public List<Vehicle> GetCustomerList(Vehicle vehi)
            {
                List<Vehicle> newL = new List<Vehicle> { vehi };
                return new List<Vehicle> { vehi };

            }

            [WebMethod]
            public void simpleCase()
            {
                Vehicle obj = new Vehicle();
                obj.VehicleID = "KL-9876";
                obj.VehicleType = "Nissan";
                obj.VehicleOwner = "Sanjiva";
                GetCustomerList(obj);
            }
    }



    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string VehicleID { get; set; }
        public string VehicleType { get; set; }
        public string VehicleOwner { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: Well you cannot capture details of Vehicle from the test form, as you normally input string, int all those basic type, you should find a way to consume this service by a another test app and pass in the object by actually populating all its components

Comment: @V4Vendetta could you just take a look at the edited part of the code and check if im returning the object properly pls?

Answer (score 3):

The method as declared expects a Vehicle object, which is something you cannot type into a form, hence the message. In a form you can obviously enter primitive types only (int, etc)

Answer (score 2):

To test non-primitive parameter types, you need to create a test application which consumes the web-service, so create a new app (windows/web it doesn't really matter) in the same solution as your web service.  Add a Web Reference to the service in the same solution.  Then consume the service as per usual (i.e. create an instance of the service, then call the methods on it, passing in any complex parameter types).